# My Sorting Program is Not Working the sorting is not working in my program

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>::const_iterator iter;
    int limit, input;
    vector<int> v;
    cout << " Enter the limit : ";
    cin >> limit;
    cout << "Enter the numbers for array :\n ";
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        cin >> input;
    }
    v.push_back(input);

    cout << "Sorting the array :\n";
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << "Array numbers :\n";
    /* for (iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter)
    cout << *iter << endl;*/

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

I want the vector array input from user and to sort and display it
and also provide the comment from which i can understand the problem and will not make the mistakes twice

Thank You

Comment: hi! The first line of your code says you are learning from a bad source (sorry!), so maybe pick a more didactically well-structured text. Anyways. You don't say what exactly goes wrong, and what you have tried to understand and solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Take some time to explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) how many elements you add to your vector.

Comment: What does this have to do with `dsa`??? Anyway this is trivial: your `v.push_back(input);` should be **inside** the loop. Now you are only pushing one value. Voting to close.

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) and [Why using namespace std is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is here

```
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    cin >> input;
}
v.push_back(input);
```

You want to add **all** the numbers that are input, but this code only adds one number because you have `push_back` after the loop not in the loop.

This is how you should do it

```
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    cin >> input;
    v.push_back(input);
}
```